I need an efficient way to associate keywords with files on the computer, to be able to retrieve them based on the keywords
I am building a .NET file manager that will allow me to associate photos and videos on Windows with keywords to quickly find files with given tags. The problem is that files might not be in some folder that will restrict the search area. Also the program will be a tool and not the main way to operate on files, so location of data might change.
My problems are:

Somehow tracking the location of files to allow me to quickly copy/move/browse them
Storing keywords associated with files (some sort of database with one-to-many relationship that doesn't interfere with first point)

The first thing i tried was to modify metadata and add custom tags, but as it turns out the way that metadata is defined for different file formats made it really hard for me to come up with a solution (and it didn't solve searching problems).
Do you have any ideas on how could i solve this problem?
